# MS Access 2000 database will not run on an English or Japanese OS

Tags: ms-access, internationalization

My company has a few legacy MS Access 2000 databases used for project based data, 2 of these databases do not work on the English installation of MS Access 2000. And from what I hear, at least one of the two, will not work from the English OS.

I am becoming fairly handy in MS Access out of necessity more than anything, but am hoping someone has already come across this issue, and can pinpoint what I could do to fix the problem (assuming its a trivial fix).

Many thanks!
Stuart

Comment: Not run is too vague.  Any error messages?  Does the startup form show up?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

There are some instructions [in Japanese] to be followed here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815467/ja