# microsoft access "enter parameter value" after switching to office version with different language

Tags: ms-access, versions

When trying to open the microsoft access application I built using german office 2003 in a english office 2003 version, every time I open any forms I get "enter parameter value" dialog boxes.

The problem seems to be that access somehow tries to access properties starting with `Formulare!`, which is german for `Forms!` and though not available in the english language version. I could not find any direct usage of `Formulare!` when searching the code and also looking trough the properties of the problematic form.

Any ideas how I can find this the origin of the problem and fix it?

**Update:**
I found the place where `Formulare` was used, it was inside a query. I would still be interested in a way on how to search EVERYTHING relevant to the project for a specific term.

Comment: I only work in English, so this is just guessing, but have you got a language setting under options? http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-office-2010-display-language/  or http://www.econ.kuleuven.be/dinb/archive/20050617/change_office_language.html

Comment: Nope, but my goal is not to change the english version to german, but to get my application running on multiple languages.

Comment: Perhaps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338292/ms-access-2000-database-will-not-run-on-an-english-or-japanese-os

Comment: @Remou, sadly, not possible as system configuration needs to stay the same. The fix needs to be applied on the access db, as this also is the root of the problem.